# Why does C code return numbers greater than 10 as letters?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{

    int mins = 10;
    int formu = 6 * mins;

    printf("Input: %x\n", mins);
    printf("Result: %x\n", formu);
}
```

Which results in the following:

```
Input: a
Result: 3c
```

I believe for some reason, one of the types, if not both, is being generated as a "Double" and putting in an "Int" is causing a conflict.When I change either of the "%x" to "mins" or "formu" I get the following error:

```
error: data argument not used by format string [-Werror,-Wformat-extra-args]
    printf("Input: %mins\n", mins);
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
```

- why is compiler assuming that I want a double?
- Is that the reason why numbers greater than 10 are resulting in a letter conversion?

Thanks

Comment: are you asking how hex works?

Comment: No, not really. I am just confused at to why it is outputting in hex. Apologies if it is too obvious - I am fairly new to coding.

Comment: As others have pointed out by now -- it is outputting in hex because you asked it to output in hex (even if this wasn't your intention).

Comment: Yes - I got it now. I didn't know that %x or %name is different than %i. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking `printf()` to represent the numbers as [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal).

Try using `%d` or `%i` instead of `%x`. This will show them as decimal numbers.

Answer (score 2):

`x` in `%x` is a [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) format specifier and `a` is 10 in hexadecimal. This has nothing to do with doubles. If you want to print a decimal number use `%d`:

```
printf("Input: %d\n", mins);
```

See also [printf documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) for more details on format specifiers.

Comment: thank you - I didn't know the difference the letter following % could cause.

Comment: And a shameless plug: if you don't want to worry about format specifiers use something like https://github.com/cppformat/cppformat

Answer (score 2):

The `%x` format specifier tells `printf` to output the given integer value in hexadecimal.

If you want the output to be decimal, use `%d`.

Also, you need to make sure that each format specifier is given an argument of the proper type.  So `%d`, `%x`, and %u`require an`int`, while`%f`required a`double`.  Using the wrong format specifier results in [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

For more details, see the man page for [printf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html)